# How to compare two values in different columns and different rows, related to an ID

Tags: iteration, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm starting to learn Power BI and metrics with DAX and some help will be apreciated, please. I would need to know how, in a sorted table (by ID, Modification and Date), of data already defined by fields ([ID, Modification, Fecha(=Date), V_INICIAL, V_FINAL, RESULT]), I can compare values ​​of different rows and columns, regardless of the number of iterations. My objective is to calculate a measure that returns the Number of different IDs per type of Modification, which meet the "OK" Result. This result compares, for each value of the Modification field, the value of the V_INITIAL of the first iteration, with the value of the V_FINAL of the last iteration, of the Modification. And if both values ​​are different, the Result is "OK", since the modification has been made. Otherwise it is "NOT_OK" because there is no modification. Thank you very much for help! ;)[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqwWi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This calculated column works with your example data (where [Mod] is the [Modificación]-column):

N.B. This is by no means an optimised code. I tried to keep it as simple and easy to understand as possible.

```
Resultado = 
var current_ID = [ID]
var current_mod = [Mod]

var maxDate = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('DataTable'[Fecha]);
    FILTER(
        ALL('DataTable');
        'DataTable'[ID] = current_ID && 'DataTable'[Mod] = current_mod
    )
)

var minDate = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN('DataTable'[Fecha]);
    FILTER(
        ALL('DataTable');
        'DataTable'[ID] = current_ID && 'DataTable'[Mod] = current_mod
    )
)

var initialState = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('DataTable'[v_inicial]);
    FILTER(
        ALL('DataTable');
        'DataTable'[Fecha] = minDate && 'DataTable'[ID] = current_ID && 'DataTable'[Mod] = current_mod
    )
)

var finalState = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('DataTable'[v_final]);
    FILTER(
        ALL('DataTable');
        'DataTable'[Fecha] = maxDate && 'DataTable'[ID] = current_ID && 'DataTable'[Mod] = current_mod
    )
)
return

SWITCH(
    TRUE();
    [Fecha] = maxDate && initialState <> finalState; "OK";
    [Fecha] = maxDate; "Not_OK";
    BLANK()
)
```